# Connecting GND to PE to improve touch sensors sensitivity

Tags: grounding, mains, capacitive

I am designing a smart light switch based on a microcontroller, with touch buttons. The design consists of two PCBs: a low voltage one for power (230 V) and an extra low voltage one for control (3.3 V and 24 V), with isolated signals from mains. Considering the capacitive touch buttons, is it advisable to connect the digital ground to earth? What are the recommended practices, and how the connection should be made - direct, through a resistor, a capacitor, an RLC filter, another method?

The goal would be to improve the sensitivity of the sensors. I personally don't see any issue with that, but I was wondering if there was any unforeseen problems that may arise from such connection.

Comment: Can you edit your question to tell us how you are isolating the digital power from the AC supply? Can you also tell us which countries this will be used in?